# Adding total session time

Tags: scripts, pipe

I'm trying to get the total session time a user has had in a month using the command last in a script.

```
last user | egrep -i month | tr -s ' ' '/' | cut -f11 -d/
```

when adding the results I'm using `expr` to add the times, but I'm unable to get the total of hours and minutes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `last user` and also the output of `last user | egrep -i month | tr -s ' ' '/' | cut -f11 -d/ ` as well as exactly what you pass to `expr` so we know what data you are trying to parse.

Comment: By the way, `egrep` is deprecated, please use `grep -E` but in this case, you don't even need it, just use `grep -i`.